# How to update multiple records at the same time?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want update more than one rows with same id in code-igniter. Only first data is being update. I want to update multiple data

**Controller**

```
  public function edit_curriculum_details($id) {

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $post = $this->input->post();

             $param = array(
                'course_id' => $post['course_id'],
                'introduction' => $post['introduction_curriculum'],
                'type' => $post['type'],
                'question' => $post['question_curriculum'],
                'answer' => $post['answer_curriculum'],
            );

            $where = array('course_id' => $id);
            $data['add'] = $this->Model->update_data('tbl_common', $param, $where);
}
```

Model
 function update_data($table, $param, $where) {

```
    $this->db->where($where);

    $this->db->update($table, $param);

    return true;
}
```

**view**

```
<input  class="form-control" name="question_curriculum" value="<?php echo $course['question']; ?>
```

**DB**

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| common_id | introduction | question            | answer  | type       | course_id |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 64        | curriculum   | Question curriculum | answer1 | curriculum | 29        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 65        | curriculun   | Question curriculum | answer1 | curriculum | 29        |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: what is there in  update_data() function ? and why are you adding 'course_id' in $param array ?

Comment: Add the **Model** model code also.

Comment: there may be many courses question and answer. so i need to select no. of question and answer then update. now only fetch one first row records. eg. id 64.Array ( [common_id] => 64 [introduction] => curriculum [question] => Question curriculum [answer] =>answer1

[type] => curriculum [course_id] => 29 )

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `update_batch()` method in your model. For more details on how to prepare data, please check the documentation at: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data